# REPEATABLE_READ on Oracle using JPA in Spring

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g, spring-annotations

when I try to set isolation level using spring annotation to REPEATABLE_READ on Oracle DB I get:
**java.sql.SQLException: READ_COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE are the only valid transaction levels.** - (ORA-17030)

It's a way to deal with this?

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
@Override
public List<ToMq> getAndChange1000NotForwarded() {
    String queryText = "SELECT c FROM ToMq c WHERE c.forwarded = 0 AND";
    TypedQuery<ToMq> query = em.createQuery(queryText, ToMq.class);
    query.setMaxResults(1000);
    List<ToMq> resultList = query.getResultList();

    Date current = new Date();
    for (ToMq toMq : resultList) {
        toMq.setForwarded(Boolean.TRUE);
        toMq.setForwardTimestamp(current);
    }
    save(resultList);

    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: You heard the database. If it doesn't support `REPEATABLE_READ`, you can't have it.

Comment: I thought that it might JPA with Spring or driver doesn't support that isolation level.

Comment: `ORA-17030` is an oracle error, not JPA, Spring or driver error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ORA-17030 error message is JDBC error message produced by Oracle JDBC driver. According to [Oracle 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#i17856) documentation the following database transaction isolation levels are supported:

- Read-Commited (default)
- Serializable
- Read-Only

therefore it's not possible to force *Repeatable-Read* (ANSI/ISO) isolation level with Oracle database.

Comment: Hi there. Is there a way, in such a case, to tell Spring to use the default transaction isolation? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean 'Read-Commited' for Oracle DB as the default transaction isolation? If yes, then [@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html#DEFAULT) is the way you go.